# Divide a number among four columns, with whole numbers only (some will be less than others)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet where I want to take a number in one column, then divide it up among 4 columns.  Each column has to be a whole number, with all 4 columns totaling the original number.

IE:
Total number:  11  (11/4=2.75)

Column A:  3
Column B:  3
Column C:  3
Column D:  2
(SUM A-B=11)

Not sure how to handle, but seems like something with rounding up and then maybe something based on the decimal part of the original total (the original total will ALWAYS be a whole number, so the decimal should only ever .25, .5, .75).

Bonus brownie points if you can make the number of columns dynamic...  ;)  (icing on the cake, NOT a requirement though)

Comment: Can there be negative numbers in the results? (e.g. with value 11 and 5 columns, 3, 3, 3, 3, -1)

Comment: No, always positive.

Comment: IE:  I have 11 units to build, and 4 queues to divide them up in.  Wanting to keep them all as equal as possible (so should only have a deviation of one unit across the queues (IE: 3,3,3,2 and NOT 4,3,2,2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, with 4 columns...

Assume the setting:

```
A1 = "Units"
B1 = 11
C1 = "Columns"
D1 = 4

B3 = =IF(COLUMN()>$D$1,"",ROUNDUP(($B$1-IF(COLUMN()=1,0,SUM($A$3:A3)))/($D$1-COLUMN()+1),0))
```

Then drag to D3, and **last** to A3, to get:

```
     A        B        C        D
1    Units   11        Columns  4
2 
3    3        3        3        2
```

---

```
=IF(COLUMN()>$D$1,
```

If the column is after the number of columns, put blank.

```
ROUNDUP(($B$1-IF(COLUMN()=1,0,SUM($A$3:A3)))/($D$1-COLUMN()+1),0),
        ^     ^------------1--------------^
        ^---------------2-----------------^                  ^
        |--------------------------3-------------------------|
```

If it's the first column, remove 0 (1) from the total units (2) and divide by total columns (3) before rounding.

Else, take what's left (2) [total minus the sum from the fist column] and divide by the remaining number of columns (3).

Comment: @nixda Okay, added some explanation!

Comment: I tested your formula: `13` results in 4,4,4,1 - but the OP wants 4,3,3,3 in this case, not? See his last comment "*Wanting to keep them all as equal as possible*"

Comment: @nixda I guess... I'll see if I can try make something like that. It's definitely more complicated though.

Comment: @nixda That was a little easier than I thought, though it required a little more thinking. Updated!

Comment: Trying to re-create what you have exactly, but confused about the wording on the formulas in Row3...  Can you clarify?

Comment: @BondUniverse Maybe [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dDNVbWtMajZHU25NV2o3RjVrUXYyVUE#gid=0) could help? `COLUMN()` retrieves the column number in the excel sheet. If `COLUMN()` is in column A, it will return 1, if it's in column B, it returns 2, etc. And the other parts should be easy to understand, it's just the logic that is a bit unique maybe, but that's difficult to explain too! the numbers between the parens refer to the parts I grouped in the explanation from the formula.

Comment: Ok, I see that works now.  Have to figure out how to adjust it to fit my needs (namely that it won't start in column A, but a later column, but that's not what I originally asked for and you came up with a good solution to my question, thank you!